# Reading/Accessing 2d/3d array

Tags: php, arrays

I did a query on a table that returned two columns of data with 5 rows. I stored these in an array but I can't figure out how to access the data. This is the result of the array:

```
/*
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [contributions] => 99
        [key_projects] => 4
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [contributions] => 2
        [key_projects] => 26
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [contributions] => 1
        [key_projects] => 26
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [contributions] => 0
        [key_projects] => 52
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [contributions] => 0
        [key_projects] => 53
    )
)
*/

$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

If I do echo $result_array[0][0] I get Array 0 echo'd.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result_array[0]['contributions'];  // displays: 99
echo $result_array[4]['key_projects'];  // displays: 53
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fetch_assoc withc means your returned arrays will use the keys from your query
so you need to use those to access the data:

```
echo $result_array[0]['contributions'];
//or
foreach($result_array as $row){
    echo "Contributions:".$row['cotributions'].", Key Projects".$row['key_projects']."\n";
}
```

If you want to use $result_array[0][0] use mysqli_fetch_row instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

As you are fetching associative array, you have to use names as array indexes.

```
foreach ($result_array as $v){
  echo 'key project: '.$v['key_projects'].'<br>';
  echo 'contributions: '.$v['contributions'].'<hr/>';
}
```